# A nonlinear optimization problem with difficult Kuhn-Tucker system of equations

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I know about the sufficient optimality theorem Kuhn-Tucker, and this problem can use the Kuhn-Tucker theorem directly, but ridiculously, I got stuck on the system of equations to find one root for optimization value. Hope someone can help me or give me some hint to solve it. Thanks.

> Find the minimum of $\theta(x,y,z) = (x + 3)^2 + (y-2)^2 +(z-4)^2 + 12$, with $x, y,z \in R$ which satisfies $g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -3x + 2y -8z + 2 \le 0$ and $h(x,y,z) = x  + 3y + 5z = 1$

Using Kuhn-Tucker theorem, I need to solve the system of equation and in equation:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\nabla \theta(x) + u\nabla g(x) + vB= 0 \\
g(x) \le 0 \\
Bx = d \\
ug(x) = 0 \\
u \ge 0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Here $B = \left[ \begin{matrix}1& 3 &5\end{matrix} \right]$

Which is equivalent to:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(2x + 6) + u(2x - 3) + v = 0 (1)\\
(2y - 4) + u(2y + 2) + 3v = 0 (2)\\
(2z - 8) + u(2z - 8) + 5v = 0 (3)\\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -3x + 2y -8z + 2 \le 0 (4)\\
u(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -3x + 2y -8z + 2) = 0 (5)\\
x + 3y + 5z = 1 (6)\\
u \ge 0 (7)
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I calculated $1 * (1) + 3 * (2) + 5 * (3)$, then use (6), I come to conclusion that $35v - 35u = 44$. From this I can conclude that $u \neq 0$, therefore, we have this system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(2x + 6) + u(2x - 3) + v = 0 \\
(2y - 4) + u(2y + 2) + 3v = 0 \\
(2z - 8) + u(2z - 8) + 5v = 0 \\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -3x + 2y -8z + 2 = 0\\
x + 3y + 5z = 1 \\
u \ge 0 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

And this is where I got stuck

Comment: I'm curious why $35\nu-35u=44$ implies that $u\neq 0$. Why wouldn't it be possible for $\nu=44/35$? (I actually think it's *true* that $u \neq 0$, I just don't follow your logic.)

Comment: Ah, sorry for not explaining clear enough. After finding $v$, we can easily find that $x = -127 \over 35$, $y = 4 \over 35$, $z = 6 \over 7$. Then we replace those values into (4), which will not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: OK. So if you're certain (4) is satisfied with equality, then you can use it to eliminate the quadratic terms from the objective. Maybe that will help

Comment: I don't think that you can do that. The statements that $\overline{x}, \overline{y}, \overline{z}$ are values that make $\theta$ smallest is not equivalent to the fact that $\overline{x}, \overline{y}, \overline{z}$ are solution of the system of equation. That is because Kuhn-Tucker theorem is just sufficient optimality condition. So I don't think you can replace (4) to the original $\theta$ function.

Comment: Well that isn't the final step, to be sure. But once you have established that $u$ is nonzero, then it must also be true that $g(x,y,z)=0$. Again, I do not know if it helps but it is plainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

$$\theta_{min}=\theta(x_0,y_0,z_0)=63-\frac{3 \sqrt{132685}}{35}$$
$${x_0}=1-\frac{54 \sqrt{132685}}{7805},\;{y_0}=\frac{61 \sqrt{132685}}{15610}-\frac{5}{2},\;{z_0}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3 \sqrt{132685}}{3122}$$

Used free CAS Maxima

http://maxima.sourceforge.net/